# ¿Porque eclipse no compila?

Tags: eclipse

No queria lanzar una pregunta de estas pero tengo problemas, al abrir eclipse el codigo aparece sin color y cuando quiero compilar el proyecto solo me muestra dos opciones:

```
Select what to run
Ant Build
Ant Build
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]